# How do I check whether or not a property is true in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to print an image only if the `HD` property in the object is set to true. I am also trying to the get the number assigned to an element and print an image that many times. (To different functions).

```
var movies = {
    "movies": [{
        "title": "Blue Streak",
        "year": 1999,
        "starring": "Martin Lawrence, Luke Wilson",
        "HD": true,
        "description": "Blue Streak is a 1999 American buddy cop comedy film directed by Les Mayfield and starring Martin Lawrence, Luke Wilson, Dave Chappelle, Peter Greene, Nicole Ari Parker and William Forsythe. The film was shot on location in California. The prime shooting spot was Sony Pictures Studios which is located in Culver City, California.",
        "photo": "data/blue-Streak.jpg",
        "rating": 4
    }
```

So for every movie where `HD` is set to `true` I want to show an image. Also for the rating, I want to show that many stars. The function I tried have not worked. Please help!

Comment: can you post the code that you've tried?

Comment: Loop through the `movies.movies` array and check the `HD` property as you go.

Comment: Also note that *nothing* about the data you have is JSON. It's an array of objects. I've edited the title and content to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for changing that. When I try to loop through I don't think I am calling the object correctly in my JS because it doesn't return anything. For instance I've tried a function like this.                                                        function load_hd() {
        var data = movies["movies"];
        var html = "";
        if (data["HD"] === true) {
            html += "<img src= 'images/HD.png'>";
        }
        $(".hd").html(html);
        $(".hd2").html(html);
    }

Comment: There is no loop in that code.

Comment: @Legionar No, you don't have to.

Comment: `movies["movies"]` is an array. You have to iterate through it. Search for `javascript loop through array`

Comment: Any other suggestions on what search for because I edited my function and it still does not work. $(document).ready(function(){
         var data = movies.movies;
        var arrayLength = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            if (data.HD === true) {
               $(".hd").append("<img src='images/HD.png'>");
            }
        }
    });

Comment: Now you have a loop, but you don't use it; `data.HD` points to the exact same thing each iteration. (try `data[i].HD`.)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should look something like...

```
for (var i = 0; i < movies.movies.length; i++){
    if(movies.movies[i].HD === true){
        var src = 'images/' + movies.movies[i].photo;
        $(".hd").append("<img src='" + src + "'");
    }

}
```

if you want to append your image to every element with a class of hd on your page.  With that you should be able to figure out how to get to your star rating, just like the HD or photo property, and then figure out what logic you need to add to put in to have your stars show up. I'd think about just adding the number as a class to the image, and then have a div after the image that gets styled based on a img with the number class with an adjacent sibling selector to access that next div.